# Не работают команды в боте телеграм на python

Tags: python, telegram, бот

у меня не работает команда Меню в боте. Работает только команда Portal.

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_text(message):
    if message.text.lower() == 'portal':
        keyboard = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True)
        keyboard.row('Факты', 'Сюжет', 'Меню')
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Portal .', reply_markup=keyboard)
        bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, 'https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steam/apps/400/header.jpg?t=1587581981');

    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Извините, но команда не принята. Попробуйте выбрать что-то из списка.');

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_text(message):
    if message.text.lower() == 'меню':
        keyboard = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True)
        keyboard.row('Portal')
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ты в главном меню', reply_markup=keyboard)


bot.polling()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сведите все пункты в одну функцию.

```
def on_portal():
    keyboard = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True)
    keyboard.row('Факты', 'Сюжет', 'Меню')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Portal - самая первая часть игры. Ниже я привела кнопки с фактами и прочим.', reply_markup=keyboard)
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, 'https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steam/apps/400/header.jpg?t=1587581981');


def on_menu():
    keyboard = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True)
    keyboard.row('Portal')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ты в главном меню', reply_markup=keyboard)


def on_unknow():
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Извините, но команда не принята. Попробуйте выбрать что-то из списка.');


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_text(message):
    cmd = message.text.lower()
    if cmd == 'portal':
        on_portal()
    elif cmd == 'меню':
        on_menu()
    else:
        on_unknow()

bot.polling()
```

Comment: спасибо, дорогой друг!